# Angular ngOnChanges not called after ngOnDestroy of parent

Tags: angular, ngoninit, ngonchanges, angular-lifecycle-hooks, ngondestroy

I have a child component which accepts an input

```
<app-custom [customModel]="customModel"></app-custom>
```

In the child component, I detect changes to the customModel input by doing:

```
@Input() customModel: CustomModel;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log('changes', changes); // -> does not get called from ngOnDestroy of parent 
}
```

In my parent component, I want to notify the child component when the parent is going to be destroyed

```
customModel = null;

ngOnDestroy() {
  let obj = new CustomModel();
  obj.state = 0;
  this.customModel = obj;
}
```

The ngOnChanges of child component is not called when the input customModel changes in parent's ngOnDestroy. Why could this be happening?

I have an audio element in the child, and the audio is still being heard even after parent is destroyed.

The ngOnChanges is called in other cases when I change the input, but not through ngOnDestroy

Comment: If parent dies, the child dies as well, therefore the PARENT - CHILD relation. You can reference the child component with ViewChild, and then call it's method from parent in ngOnDestroy

Comment: @Dino I can have multiple such children in the parent, how do I do it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because child component gets destroyed before its parent.
You can check this with a simple log inside the ngOnDestroy() method on both components.

**Update**

So if you want to stop the currently running audio just do it inside the child component when it's being destroyed.

Comment: when you change the  customModel input inside the ngOnDestroy() parent's method the child component doesn't even exist so it can't handle this.

Comment: Then how can I pass data to the child component in this case? I have an audio element in the child, and the audio keeps on playing even after parent is destroyed

Comment: just tell us more about your requirements

Comment: I have an audio element in the child component. When the parent is destroyed, the audio from child component is still being heard

Comment: you can handle this inside the ngOnDestroy() child's method